# g++ コンパイラでライブラリのリンクを行うための -L -lオプションの使い方がわからない

Tags: gcc, mingw, sdl

参考サイト(Qiita)の[ライブラリパスをコマンドラインオプションで指定する場合](https://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/9dfab147482b2ce31840#%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)という場所に乗せられている提示コード
`gcc -o sample -L/usr/local/lib/hoge -lfoo -lbar main.c` ですが、これはコマンドプロンプトでは提示画像のようなディレクトリ構造の場合どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

自分はg++を使うので `g++ -Lライブラリを探すディレクトリ　-lライブラリ名 -lライブラリ名　ファイル名.cpp ファイル名cpp` としていますが、これが間違えているのでしょうか？

提示画像は参照先であるSDLライブラリの**lib/x64/**の中の.lib.dll系の場所

ソースとヘッダーはtestディレクトリに**headerとsource**という名前でディレクトリ分けしてあります。以前間違えたときそのディレクトリには#**include ○○**がありませんよ教えてくれたので**include** パスは通っているはず。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
g++ -L../SDL2/lib/x64/ -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf Game.cpp main.cpp
```

```
    C:\Users\ユーザー名\Desktop\test\source>g++ -L../SDL2/lib/x64/-lSDL2-lSDL2_ttf main.cpp Game.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `SDL_Log'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `SDL_Log'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x17c): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `SDL_Log'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x269): undefined reference to `SDL_GetKeyboardState'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x31e): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x5ba): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x5c8): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x5dc): undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x610): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x641): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x65d): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x68e): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x71f): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x7b8): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderFillRect'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x808): undefined reference to `TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x826): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x85a): undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x886): undefined reference to `SDL_QueryTexture'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x90a): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x918): undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x926): undefined reference to `SDL_FreeSurface'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x934): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x942): undefined reference to `TTF_CloseFont'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x95d): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x96a): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x96f): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

環境 Windows 10

参考サイト:
[C/C++のコンパイルについてメモ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/9dfab147482b2ce31840)
[C++ コンパイラオプション](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-4837/Rev.html)

Comment: できればエラーメッセージ等は画像ではなくテキストとして投稿してください。コマンドプロンプトではタイトルバーを右クリック → 編集 → すべて選択、もう一度タイトルバーを右クリック → 編集 → コピーでテキストをコピーできるので、必要箇所のみ抜き出してみてください。 / フォルダ構成も正直提示された内容だけでは不十分な気がします。

Comment: 編集しました。提示画像を追加しコマンドプロンプトのメッセージも入れました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コンパイルオプションでは `-L../SDL2/lib/x64/` と指定されており64bitかのように見えますが、エラーメッセージでは

> ```
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\MATSUZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccd88skb.o:Game.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
> ```

と32bitリンカが動作しています。アーキテクチャを一致させましょう。

あと、ディレクトリ構成とファイル一覧を見る限りMinGW用ではなくVisual C++用を使用されているように見えます。コンパイラーも一致させましょう。
Windows標準のVisual C++では`SDL2.lib`等、拡張子は`.lib`となります。MinGWはこれに従っておらず独自形式で`libSDL2.a`等、拡張子は`.a`となります。

---

> g++ では拡張子を.aにする必要があってx32を指定するかg++でx64にするかしてくださいっていうことでいいのでしょうか？

使用するプラットフォーム、コンパイラーを定めてください。Windowsを使うのだとは思われますが、

- x64とするのかx86とするのか
- コンパイラーはVisual C++を使用するのか、MinGWを使用するのか

その上で、どこからモジュールを入手したのか質問文に記載がありませんが、[公式サイト](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php)には

- SDL2-devel-2.0.12-VC.zip (Visual C++ 32/64-bit)
- SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw.tar.gz (MinGW 32/64-bit)

が用意されているので、適切なものを導入してください。

Comment: g++ では拡張子を.aにする必要があってx32を指定するかg++でx64にするかしてくださいっていうことでいいのでしょうか？

Comment: @shosinnsya 回答を更新しました。

Comment: なるほど。そこから間違えていました。ちょっと時間があるときにまた試行錯誤します。

Answer (score 0):

`-L` および `-l` オプションを使う場合、続くディレクトリ名やライブラリ名は **スペースを挟まずに** 指定する必要があります。

**NGな例:**

```
gcc -L dir ...
      ^
```

**正しい例:**

```
gcc -Ldir ...
```

Comment: 質問ですが　以下ようにコマンド入力しても提示画像ような大量のundefined reference エラーが出るのですがどうしたらいいのでしょうか？ undefined reference  g++ -L../SDL2/lib/x64 -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf main.cpp Game.cpp     これを実行したときのディレクトリは/sourceです。../を使ってtestディレクトリつまりプロジェクトファイルに戻りそこからSDL2ライブラリのlib/x64/でそれぞれを探しているはずなのですが.......