# MinGW 環境にて regex を使用したい！(link エラー)

Tags: windows, c, mingw

MinGW 環境(Windows)でC言語のプログラムを書いています。
コンパイラーは gcc です。

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/regex/mingw-regex-2.5.1/

（09/12 14:39追記）正しくはこちらのリンクからダウンロードしました。
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/regex/2.7/regex-2.7-lib.zip/download

上記URLからダウンロードした regex に関するフォルダをプログラムの階層に入れて以下の通り実行しましたが、linkage phase にてエラーが出てしまいます。

解決法をご存じでしたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
gcc -I .\regex\include\ -L .\regex\lib\  main.c

C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8JbHKz.o:main.c:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `__imp_regfree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: こんな記事 [Setting up the `regex.h` library on Windows with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68244530/9014308), [Build a source using <regex.h> with i586-mingw32msvc-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34043223/9014308) が類似の状況かもしれませんね。表示されたエラーメッセージはもっと行数があったのでは？ 質問の内容から推測すると、紹介した記事と類似で個々のライブラリを手作業でダウンロード・インストール・設定しているように見えますが、それならば紹介記事に書かれているように環境全体を MSYS2 に切り替えて MSYS2 のパッケージ管理に任せると簡単になるのでは？ あるいは既にその環境である場合にはその辺の情報を質問に追記した方が適切な助言・回答を得やすいでしょう。

Comment: `-L` だけではライブラリファイルのあるディレクトリを指定するだけで、ライブラリファイルを指定したことにならんです。`-L` の後ろに `-l` (大文字小文字が違う) でライブラリ名も指定するといいはず（ `cygwin` ならそうなんだけど `mingw` だとちと微妙:）

Comment: .\regex\lib\ にはどのような名前のファイルがありますか?

Comment: @774RR 
なるほど。ありがとうございます。ライブラリの指定方法を調べて試してみます。

Comment: @int32_t lib以下には以下の5つのファイルがありました。
\libregex.dll.a
\libregex.la
\regex-bcc.lib
\regex.lib
\regex2.def

Comment: @774RR ライブラリ名を-l regex と指定しましたが、
skipping incompatible .\regex\lib\/regex.lib when searching for -lregex
とエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: リンク先には3つのファイルがありますが、どのファイルをダウンロードしましたか？

Comment: @cubick このコメントできづいたのですが、フォルダのURLを間違えております。これがダウンロードリンクになります。https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/regex/2.7/regex-2.7-lib.zip/download

Comment: それからこんな記事もあるようです。[g++ コンパイラでライブラリのリンクを行うための -L -lオプションの使い方がわからない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/68702/26370) オプションとディレクトリ,ライブラリ指定の間に空白をいれてはいけないのでは？

Answer (score 0):

ライブラリファイル名の先頭の `lib` と 最後の `.a` を省略して `-l` オプションに指定するので、おそらく、
`gcc -I.\regex\include\ -L.\regex\lib\  main.c -lregex.dll`

でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

`skipping incompatible` の原因はいっぱいあって悩ましいのですが

可能性１： `x86` と `x64` の不整合
あなたのダウンロードしたファイルは `x86` 用のようです。
あなたが使っているのが `mingw` (`x86`) でなくて `mingw-w64` (`x64`) であるなら違うファイルをダウンロードしなければなりません。

可能性２： `cygwin` つか ELF 系と `mingw` つか COFF 系の不整合
オイラは `cygwin` の人なので `mingw` は眼中にないのですが、あなたのダウンロードした zip 中の `regex.lib` は COFF つまり Visual C/C++ (x86) 用のようです。 mingw って COFF を GNU ld から使おうとする関係で `gcc -I../include regextest1.c -L../lib -lregex.dll` のように起動するはず。コマンドラインで `-lregex.dll` と指定すると `libregex.dll.a` というファイルを探すのが UNIX 系 `ld` の仕様っス。

なので上記２点をチェック（もしかしたら両方にハマっているパターンかも）

あとあなたのダウロードしたファイルは**開発用**ファイルしか入っていないみたいです。**実行用**に別途 `regex2.dll` なるファイルが必要ですが、この `zip` ファイルには入っていない様子。

Visual Studio 2019 の `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2019` 窓で

```
cl -nologo -utf-8 -Iinclude regtest.c lib/regex.lib
```

とすればリンクは成功しますが、実行するとよく見る `regex2.dll が見つからないため、コードの実行を継続できません` エラー窓が表示されてしまいます。

C++11 以上が使える状況なら、古い `<regex.h>` などポイして C++ 標準の `<regex>` に切り替え推奨。